Do linguists consider that vowel length marks aren't necessary for AmE (and parhaps RP,too)?
Take a word like "redeemer".  Is it conceivable that the middle vowel wouldn't be significantly longer in any native AmE speaker's idiolect?  Is the linguists' inside-baseball notion "vowel length isn't phonemic in AmE" a "the tomato is not a vegetable" kind of showing off?  Surely both native speakres and second language learners would be helped by a length mark as in [rɪˈdiːmər] ?
And it is not as if /i/ always takes the length mark ('anybody').
/i/ occurs both long and short in both AmE and brE and it is probably just coincidence that they don't occur in a minimal pair.

It’s not “just coincidence”, no – it’s an inherent property. There’s no need to include the length marks in the phoneme, since it’s automatic: all tense/free vowels in American English are longer in (primarily or secondarily) stressed syllables and shorter in unstressed ones, a typologically very common distribution that is also found in languages like Italian and Icelandic. (Even lax/checked vowels are a bit longer in stressed syllables – e.g., the /ɪ/’s in ˈsyllable and sylˈlabic – but the difference is less marked there.)

Also, you ask about vowel length being phonemic, but then you give a phonetic transcription (square brackets). There is no doubt that a phonetic transcription, which describes the surface sounds actually made by speakers, should include the length mark. That doesn’t mean a phonemic transcription needs to. A phonetic transcription should also include information that an American /r/ is generally bunched and labialised [ɹ̠ʷ ~ ɻʷ], and the last syllable is generally a single rhotacised vowel [ɚ] rather than a sequence of vocalic schwa and consonantal /r/.

"There is no doubt that a phonetic transcription, which describes the surface sounds actually made by speakers, should include the length mark. " That is all I wanted   @Janus Bahs Jacquet.  I assume you are contradicting the notion that length isn't necessary to mark in dictionaries because vowel quality predicts the length for native speakers.

No, I’m agreeing with the notion that length marks in dictionaries are not necessary. Dictionaries usually give phonemic transcriptions that then need to be interpreted and submitted to various dialect-dependent transformations to get to the end result that comes out of any given speaker’s mouth. In a phonemic transcription, the vowel’s position in relation to word stress will predict its length, so it’s not necessary to indicate it.

so if one speaker says "it" normally and another "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiit" like in Michael jackson's song "beat it" it is cool?  it is not the dictionary-maker's concern?  Linguistics arises by superposing absurdity on grammar.- there cannot be a doubt about it.@Janus Bahs Jacquet

Of course it’s not the lexicographer’s concern if some random speaker somewhere pronounces it with an unnaturally long vowel, or even if a whole dialect does, as long as it’s regular. That’s not what lexicography is about. You seem to be the one trying to “superpose absurdity” on linguistics. Dia- and idiolectal differences in pronunciation, incidentally, have nothing to do with grammar.

OALD says
"Some variant pronunciations are represented by the special use of /i/ and /u/ (without a length mark /ː/). /i/ represents a weak vowel that can be sounded either as /iː/ or /ɪ/ or a compromise between them."
wrong.  These are not "variant pronunciations" .
"anybody" has a clear short [i] that is not [ɪ] [i] and [i:] belong in a 'pronunciation guide" - they are different sounds that make different words. Whether they are distinct "phonemes" is linguist mumbo-jumbo. @Janus Bahs Jacquet

No, it’s not. OALD is based on British English, where the second and fourth vowels in anybody do indeed fall on a continuum between [i] and [ɪ]. Many of your statements about English and, in particular, about linguistics are quite simply uninformed and wrong.

wrong of course.  OALD is for both GenAm and RP.  "lose a debate and insult/name-call" is a UNIVERSAL behavior on internet fora. @Janus Bahs Jacquet

StackExchange isn't about debates.

Well, what do you mean by "necessary"? Necessary for what purpose?

to add non-redundant information about pronunciation.  Staying away from linguistic inside-baseball for a second.  Imagine an average person who looks up a new word (to him/her) in a dictionary that only has a phonemic transcription (nowadays they are mostly electonic and include audios of the pronunciation) - how does that help him/her figure out the pronunciation? @Draconis
♦

@SK Well, if they're a native speaker, they'll handle the non-phonemic parts automatically. You don't need to tell a native English-speaker to aspirate the stops in "potato"; they'll do that without even thinking about it (and in fact will generally have trouble not doing it if you tell them otherwise).

let us say that your average non-linguist person is looking at a written word.  you are saying they would know where to aspirate it?  Actually even linguists wouldn't know unambiguously ("Wisconsin", "mediterranean" etc.).  You are saying that if they look up "equinoctial" they would know how to say "iːkwɪˈnɑːkʃl" without audio (which has TWO length markings by the way)?  I am runnig into a linguist brick wall of denying the obvious  @Draconis ♦

@SK Yes, I'm saying native English-speakers generally aren't consciously aware of aspiration (unless they speak another language that uses it, like Hindi). They'll aspirate stops in certain environments and not aspirate them in others, without even thinking about it.

@SK No, OALD is based on BrE; where AmE pronunciation differs, it is listed separately, following the British one, and still using transcriptions that are based on BrE (with length marks, for example). And I did not insult or name-call, I merely pointed out that your statements are uninformed and incorrect, which they are. It’s clear from your disparaging comments that you do not like linguistics; that does not make it invalid.

It is TOTALLY FALSE that OALD gives the AmE pronunciation only when it differs from BrE.  Someone who can make such a blatantly false statement that can be verified in one second - cannot be given ANY credence on ANYTHING - Falsus in uno, falsus in omnibus @Janus Bahs Jacquet

“If there is a difference between British and American pronunciations of a word, the British one is given first, with NAmE before the American pronunciation.” — OALD, p. R118. If you claim this is false, please provide just one example where they list a NAmE pronunciation that does not differ from the British one.

Yes, it's in fact very common not to use length marks in phonemic transcriptions of American English. If you look at Wells's transcription of General American vowel phonemes, for example, there are no length marks to be found.
I'm not aware of any dialect where length doesn't show up phonetically, conditioned by stress and following consonants. But including phonetic detail in transcriptions tends not to be helpful to native speakers, since it just clutters up the transcription for no real gain. Native speakers of American English don't need to be told to aspirate stops at the beginning of words, for example, they'll do it without even thinking about it.
It's possible to find a few minimal pairs distinguished solely by length, but this always comes from some kind of neutralization—for example, some people have "writer" [ˈɹaj.ɾɹ̩] and "rider" [ˈɹajː.ɾɹ̩], but the length difference there comes from the consonants, rather than being an inherent feature of the vowels.
EDIT: For RP, I'm afraid I can't say. As an American English speaker I have access to a lot of data about AmE pronunciations, and a lot less data about RP.

That the inherent length of vowels is affected by the linguist shibboleth  "pre-forts shortening" seems to be a myth in connected spech:
https://karolinum.cz/data/clanek/283/Philologica_1_2014_09_Fejlova.pdf  @Draconis♦

@SK That paper is very interesting, but it never claims that pre-fortis shortening is a myth or doesn't exist.

EVERYTHING linguistics says about language that your parents or schoolteachers don't say is either an outright lie or a deceptive half-truth.  It is a tough contest between "vowel length is not phonemic" and "pre-fortis shortening" as to which is a more shameless lie @Draconis ♦  I think it is getting found out and some linguistics departments are closing or getting their funding cut drastically.

@SK Do you have any evidence for that? Your questions here seem to be more focused on ranting that all of linguistics is a lie than actually getting answers, and that's not really how this site works.

"The results suggest that the difference in the duration of pre-fortis and pre-lenis vowels is considerably lower in connected speech than in previously reported results," If that isn't a politely worded accusation of error/dishonesty, I don't know what is  @Draconis

@SK There's a big difference between "this effect is stronger when speaking words in isolation than when speaking fluently" and "this effect doesn't exist".

this quote from the paper "These results seem to suggest that pre-fortis shortening is hard to detect in fluent speech. In other words, the differences in vowel durations before fortis and lenis consonants reported from carefully controlled speech are, naturally, somewhat blurred in communicative contexts, even for native speakers." suggests that the bald assertion of "pre-fortis shortening" needs to be nuanced.  In fact to the extent that it exists, perhaps some other underlying phenomenon is causing it @draconis

@SK Sure, it's possible there's another explanation. But that doesn't mean the phenomenon doesn't exist, or that everything about linguistics is a lie. If you ask questions on a linguistics site, you're going to get answers from people who believe in linguistics.

We need to stay away from dogma. Let us take the vowel length thingy.  There is a song called "witchy woman" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc0988XxoXI
what happens to the last vowel of "witchy" as it is lengthened?  the word becomes "witchay" (this is featured in a "Seinfeld" episode).  @draconis

@SK Vowel length in speech doesn't necessarily correlate with vowel length in singing. Cf the old joke about Catholics stretching "gloria" over eighteen syllables.
